# Set global description for Jenkins instance

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Using Jenkins we would like to set this global description by default. We have used groovy scripts to set other global variables but I'm struggling to find what methods / classes I need to call in order to set this description for our Jenkins instance. I see many description plugins for builds but this is instead the description you see on the Jenkins homepage (not per build). In the image below I clicked "Edit description" and then typed "test" in the box and pressed save.

That's the workflow we'd like to automate using Jenkins groovy code :)

[image: description block in jenkins]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The description that is shown in your image, is not a global Jenkins description but rather the description of the current view you are looking on - in this case the `All` view. If you switch to another view it will change.
To modify this via groovy code you need to modify the description of the view by its name:

```groovy
Jenkins.instance.getView('all').setDescription("My New Description")
```

If you do want a global message that will appear always regardless of the selected view you can use the **System Message** option (configurable via the *Configure System* menu):

> This message will be displayed at the top of the Jenkins main page.
> This can be useful for posting notifications to your users

To update the system message via groovy code you can use the flowing:

```groovy
Jenkins.instance.setSystemMessage("My System Message")
```

Comment: I only got the notification now and have logged off my computer but 100% I'll try this tomorrow and get back to you. I had no idea about the concept of "views" so that'd probably explain why it was difficult to find the right docs.

Comment: works perfectly thanks a mill